# Как в vim применить две разные темы оформления?

Tags: vim, vimrc

У меня такая ситуация, имеется два компьютера на которых в vim мне хотелось бы использовать разные темы оформления, учитывая то, что `.vimrc` файл один на двоих. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему? на обеих машинах используется консольный vim в ubuntu 18.04.

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вот этот плагин решит вашу проблему:

https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc

Comment: *“Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”*